# Getting error in Activeadmin NoMethodError - undefined method `login'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, activeadmin

I am using active admin for admin side.

I installed active-admin gem and executed `rails g active_admin:install`.

After that when I tried to open login page for admin. I am getting this error.

> NoMethodError - undefined method `login' for #:

Comment: can you please post the login page view here...hope you anywhere use `current_user.login` there is no such method for admin user name `login` but if you want to check if admin user is logged in? or not then just use `admin_user_signed_in?`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the content of the admin_user.rb is similar to the following;

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :login
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :login
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding

attr_accessor :login

to admin_user.rb fixed the problem for me.

Comment: You should accept the answer which I posted then, bcoz it has the option mentioned as `attr_accessor :login` code in the example I have shared.

Answer (score 0):

### A possible reason

The devise config in an initializer: `config.authentication_keys = [:login]`

### Possible solution

Add `authentication_keys: [:email]` to the device config in your `AdminUser` class like:

```rb
# app/models/admin_user.rb

devise :database_authenticatable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, authentication_keys: [:email]
```